# Clicking a Button in a formbox with selenium WebDriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and selenium. I am trying to click a button in a formbox, but cannot click, only highlight the button. I am trying to click on the button named "Delivery System"

My code is:

```
delivery_system = browser.find_element_by_name("Delivery System")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", delivery_system)
delivery_system.click()
```

The html is:

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol3Pb.png)

When I try my code it just highlights the button, but doesn't click/follow it?

ANy ideas?

Comment: Hello, please attach the html code and if there is an error with your click?

Answer (score 0):

i would advice you change

```
delivery_system = browser.find_element_by_name("Delivery System")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", delivery_system)
delivery_system.click()
```

to

```
delivery_system = browser.find_element_by_name("Delivery System").click()
```

or select by classname

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.browseLink').click()
```